# How to properly name include guards in c++

Tags: c++

I have 3 header files:

```
misc.h
MyForm.h
Registration.h
```

In misc.h file I put

```
#ifndef MISC_H
#define MISC_H
#endif
```

In MyForm.h, I put

```
#include "misc.h"
#include "Registration.h"
```

And in Registration.h, I put

```
#include "misc.h"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"have redirection error"* you should post it here then and change question title accordingly.

Comment: Do you have the #endif at the bottom of misc.h?

Comment: How is "redirection error" related here? [mcve] please. / `#pragma once`?

Comment: should i put #pragma once at the top of each files?

Comment: `#pragma once` is non-standard and only supported by some compilers

Comment: @dwo, do I need to put #endif at the bottom of  misc.h?

Comment: this will sound stupid, but is your code *between*  `#define MISC_H`
and `#endif` ?

Comment: I use visual studio for c++

Comment: What's a "redirection error"? Is it something you translated yourself or does the error message actually use those words?

Comment: Wrong approach (after your edit adding error messages). You need to read more about C++ and its preprocessor. Then you should be able to correct these (new) errors by yourself. **StackOverflow is not a *fix-my-bugs* service**. BTW, provide some [MCVE] in your question

Answer (score 15):

How to name include guards is somewhat opinion based, but a few recommendations can be made:

1) Don't make them short as they are then likely to clash with other macros defined in other files or the implementation or libraries you use.

2) Make them contain a project specific prefix in an attempt to make them unique and unambiguous.

3) If your project contains multiple sub-parts "modules"/"libraries" etc, make the guard name contain the name of the module to make them unique within your project - include the file name as well.

4) Make sure not to use reserved names such as `NULL`, names starting with a number or names that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter as well as names containing consecutive underscores; all such names are reserved for the implementation to use.

5) Use all uppercase for macros (just a common convention).

For a file named "baz.h" in a project named "foo", in submodule "bar", I'd name the guard `FOO_BAR_BAZ_H`.

PS. Make sure *all* your headers use include guards (except in *very* special and rare cases). Otherwise you are inviting trouble with multiple definition errors and more.

Comment: please accept this as the answer, thx!

Answer (score 3):

You should use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in every header file and nothing should be outside the include guards.

The name of include guards can be anything as long as it is unlikely to clash with any other name. An example for your MyForm.h might be:

```
#ifndef MYFORM_HEADER_
#define MYFORM_HEADER_

#include "misc.h"
#include "Registration.h"

/* all code here */

#endif
```

It is also important that nothing is written outside of the include guards in a header file.

Answer (score 3):

> How to properly name include guards in c++

Usual convention is to only use upper case characters. Numbers and underscores are fine too except not as the first character. The include guard must be unique: The name must not be used for anything else in the program.

The name must not be reserved, so you must not use `NULL` for example. Also, all names that begin with underscore followed by a capital letter, as well as all names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved.

`MISC_H` is not reserved, but keep in mind that if you have another `misc.h` in another path, then you cannot use the same include guard. It's usually better to use longer names to uniquely identify the file. Perhaps use some kind of prefix, such as company name, or your own name. Typically `_H` suffix is used to separate from non-guard macros.

If you have problems with coming up unique names that aren't reserved, or just feel that it's tedious, then you could use `#pragma once` instead. Be warned that it isn't standard. I've heard rumours about exotic compilers that don't support it, as well as convoluted build processes where hard linked files didn't get guarded as they should. If you encounter such problems, it's trivial to simply add the header guards afterwards.

---

Your other headers appear to lack include guards. If you include them in any header, then there will probably be trouble. It's a good practice to guard all header files.

---

> do I need to put #endif at the bottom of misc.h?

Yes. The guard only protects the code that is between the define and endif.

Comment: "names that begin with underscore and capital letter" - you mean "names that begin with underscore and are followed by a capital letter" .. as a general rule of thumb I'd generally advice *never* to name *any* identifier with a leading underscore, nor *ever* use consecutive underscores - that way you never get into trouble with reserved names. :-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl ah, that was dangerously ambiguous indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put individual [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in *every* header, notably in `MyForm.h`:

```
#ifndef MYFORM_H
#define MYFORM_H
#include "misc.h"
#include "Registration.h"
// etc...
#endif /*MYFORM_H*/
```

and in `Registration.h`:

```
#ifndef REGISTRATION_H
#define REGISTRATION_H
// actual code
// etc...
#endif /*REGISTRATION_H*/
```