# Segmentation fault on strcpy even though I am using malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, strcpy

I am trying to make a Doubly Linked List in C.

And I get a Segmentation Fault even though I use malloc.

Here is my code so far.

**list.h**

```
#ifndef _LIST_
#define _LIST_

typedef struct listnode
{
    char * data;
    struct listnode * next;
    struct listnode * prev;
}listnode;

typedef struct list
{
    listnode * firstnode; // it will point to the first element in the list
    int size; // the size of the list
}list;

list create_list();
void insert_first_element(char *, list);

#endif
```

**list.c**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

list create_list()
{
    list L;
    L.firstnode= NULL;
    L.size = 0;

    return L;
}

void incert_first_element(char * d, list L)
{
    listnode * N= (listnode *)malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    
    strcpy(N->data, d); // <-- I get Segmentation Fault Here

    if(L.firstnode != NULL)
    {
        N->next=L.firstnode;
        N->prev=L.firstnode->prev;
        L.firstnode->prev=N;
        L.firstnode=N;
    }
    else
    {
        N->next=NULL;
        N->prev=N;
        L.firstnode=N;
    }
    L.size++;
    return 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(void)
{
   list L = create_list();
   incert_first_element("test",L);
  
   return 0;
}
```

Any idea what is causing the Segmentation Fault?

Because any problems I found when googling were caused by the lack of malloc, but here I do implement it.

Comment: yeah, clearly `N->data` isn't initialized

Comment: Just for your information, your include guard should probably not start with an underscore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688652/2770331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code

```
listnode * N= (listnode *)malloc(sizeof(listnode));

strcpy(N->data, d); // <-- I get Segmentation Fault Here
```

allocates a `listnode` structure but the `data` field is a *pointer* on a `char`, so it's not initialized by the `malloc` call.

The second line should be replaced for instance by a `strdup` call

```
N->data = strdup(d);
```

deallocation should also be done in 2 passes. First `free(N->data)` then `free(N)`

Comment: OP is passing the list by value so the insert function will have no effect on return. Arg should be `List *L` with `L.` --> `L->` in the body.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `incert_first_element` receives a copy of the `list` structure and modifies it. This has no effect on the `list` object of the caller. You should instead pass a pointer to the caller's `list` object.
- the `incert_first_element` function allocates a new `listnode` object, but not for the string. The member `data` is a pointer, not an array, `malloc()` does not initialize it so `strcpy(N->data, d);` copies the characters into an uninitialized pointer, invoking undefined behavior (a segmentation fault stooping the program). You should allocate a copy of the string with `N-strcpy(N->data, d);`
- you insert the node at the beginning of the doubly linked list, thus it is incorrect to set `N->prev = N;` the previous node should be set to `NULL` in both cases.
- in **list.c**, you should `#include "list.h"` **after** the standard headers.

Here is a modified version:

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

typedef struct listnode {
    char *data;
    struct listnode *next;
    struct listnode *prev;
} listnode;

typedef struct list {
    listnode *firstnode; // it will point to the first element in the list
    int size; // the size of the list
} list;

list create_list(void);
void insert_first_element(list *, const char *);
#endif
```

**list.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

list create_list(void) {
    list L = { NULL, 0 };
    return L;
}

void insert_first_element(list *L, const char *d) {
    listnode *N = malloc(sizeof(*N));
    if (N == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    N->data = strdup(d);
    N->prev = NULL;
    N->next = L->firstnode;

    if (L->firstnode != NULL) {
        L->firstnode->prev = N;
    }
    L->firstnode = N;
    L->size++;
    return 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(void) {
   list L = create_list();
   insert_first_element(&L, "test");
  
   return 0;
}
```